# Modular forms of infinite level

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves, modular-forms

Modular forms of the same weight $k$ and levels $m | n$ naturally embed: $$M_k(\Gamma(m)) \rightarrow M_k(\Gamma(n)),$$ and any element of the union $\bigcup M_k(\Gamma(n))$ is an actual modular form.

There are also surjective averaging maps $$M_k(\Gamma(n)) \rightarrow M_k(\Gamma(m))$$ in the other direction. (Another way to see this is that $M_k(\Gamma(n))$ is naturally isomorphic to its dual through the Petersson scalar product, which flips the direction.) We can take the projective limit $$\varprojlim M_k(\Gamma(n)).$$ I believe this is in some sense larger than $\bigcup M_k(\Gamma(n)).$

Does such an object have geometric meaning? I wonder how the set $\varprojlim M_k(\Gamma(n))$ may be related to elliptic curves.

Comment: Not sure about geometric meaning, but this kind of thing pops up naturally when you consider modular forms as elements of automorphic representations, which are subsets of functions on $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{A_Q})$ that are square-integrable (in a precise way) - the usual formulation of this does not impose any level condition, so modular forms of all levels appear in this space of square-integrable functions.

Comment: What I noticed is that if say $f$ is a newform then the vector space generated by all the $M_k(\Gamma(n))$ contains $f(nz)$ as well as $\sum_{b=0}^{n-1} f(z+b/n)$ for every $n$ so it is where lies the sequence $f_M(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n(f) e^{2i \pi n z} 1_{gcd(n,M!) = 1}$ which encodes the Riemann hypothesis for $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n(f) n^{-s}$. @PeterHumphries